# How to get the socket for MySQLi to Oracle DB connection?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, sockets, mysqli

I am new with web development. I have difficulty in connecting to an oracle DB. This code was patterned from the [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/mysql-php1-139180.html).

I am sure with the connection details except the socket.Is the socket on default? or How do I get the socket detail from the Oracle DB interface?

```
$host="site.com";
$port=1404;
$socket="/tmp/mysql.sock";
$user="admin";
$password="admin123";
$dbname="admin_table";

/* create a connection object which is not connected */
$conn = new mysqli();
$conn -> init();

/* set connection options */
$conn -> options (MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
$conn -> options (MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 200);

/* connect to MySQL server */
$conn -> real_connect ($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
        or die ('Could not connect to the database server : ' . $conn -> error . '\n');
```

I also encounter these errors:

```
Warning: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\Lot_Verification\pages\DB_Connect.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=6572 in C:\wamp\www\Lot_Verification\pages\DB_Connect.php on line 19

Warning: mysqli::real_connect() [mysqli.real-connect]: (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\Lot_Verification\pages\DB_Connect.php on line 19

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\Lot_Verification\pages\DB_Connect.php on line 20
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli` to connect to an Oracle database?

Comment: I have started using mysqli. Is there a restriction with using mysqli to Oracle db?

Comment: `mysqli` is for connecting to a MySql database - not an oracle one. [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/php_db/php_db.htm) would be a better starting place

Comment: Thanks. Last question, would this mean there is no way to integrate mysqli  to oracle db?

Comment: I do not know - never have tried it.

Comment: Those are two very-very different products, which coincidentally happen to have the same owner right now.